# Always getting empty response while using the graph search API for sharepoint document

Tags: python-3.x, api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am using following graph search API to search sharepoint document using the document id.

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

My api url :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drive/root/search(q='DlcDocId:doc id')
```

My response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": []
}
```

I am getting empty response with response code is 200.

My access token have full access with following scope

```
"scp": "Files.Read.All Group.Read.All GroupMember.Read.All User.Read User.Read.All profile openid email"
```

I want item id with item details as api response. So that we can use item id for further action. Not able to fetch the item id from search query.

I am stuck here. Please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: You can try using the item path: GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}

Comment: It is not working with path. Can you please provide the full url.

Comment: Here is the list of API's through which we can fetch the item:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Portal.Azure.com > App Registrations > [Your App Registration Name].

You will need to check your permissions there under API permissions. For accessing SharePoint items, via Microsoft Graph, we have the following settings:

**[API / Permissions name]**

**Microsoft Graph**

- Sites.Manage.All
  *(we have because we do a lot of doc management via code)*
- Sites.ReadWrite.All
- User.Read

You may just need the Sites.ReadWrite.All under Microsoft.Graph, but I wanted to provide context to do other things as well if coding against SharePoint Online.